# How do I include an icon font?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I'm trying to include icon font in my wpf application, but my icon never appears and only displays a rectangle.

**Projet structure :**

```
MyProject/
  -- Fonts/
      -- myFont.ttf
  -- MyWindow.xaml
```

**MyWindow.xaml**

```
<Label Text="&#xea21;" FontFamily="/Fonts/#myfont" />
```

"myfont" is the name of the font (the one I see after "Font name" when I double click on the file). The file's Build Action is set as "Resource".

I also tried the following :

**Using style**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:key="MyFont">
        <Setter property="TextElement.FontFamily"/Fonts/#myfont" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Label Text="&#xea21;" Style="{StaticResource MyFont}" />
```

**Using pack URI**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:key="MyFont">
        <Setter property="TextElement.FontFamily" value="v/Fonts/#myfont" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Label Text="&#xea21;" Style="{StaticResource MyFont}" />
```

None of them work. Moreover, the last one (with pack URI) generates an error. Something like an "index out of range error" (I have VS in French so I can't tell what the message is in English).

Already tried to find a solution on the internet, but all I could find was using pack URI, or checking that the name of the font is correct or that Build Action is set to "Resource".

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I precise that I don't want to use Blend. I would like to manage to do it directly in code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wpf supports embedded fonts - the easiest way to set these up is to assign a font to a visual element, such as a label via the font family property. I normally use blend (part of visual studio) which displays a font manager button. You can then embed the font in your application from there.

Otherwise MSDN have a page which details other options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you edit the .csproj file for your project and add the item group...

```html
  <ItemGroup>
    <BlendEmbeddedFont Include="Fonts\ahronbd.ttf">
      <IsSystemFont>True</IsSystemFont>
      <All>True</All>
      <AutoFill>True</AutoFill>
      <Uppercase>True</Uppercase>
      <Lowercase>True</Lowercase>
      <Numbers>True</Numbers>
      <Punctuation>True</Punctuation>
    </BlendEmbeddedFont>
  </ItemGroup>
```

You will need a Fonts folder with that .ttf file in there as part of your solution folder. This isn't pretty, but it will work without relying on additional tools.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do, but as I said, I can't make it work =(

Comment: You're trying via code, I'm suggesting the UI led way. Does that also not work?

Comment: What are you calling the UI led way ?

Comment: I never used Blend and it's not installed on my computer. Isn't there a way to make it work without Blend ?

Comment: Doing wpf without blend is like html without a design view, seriously worth looking at if you have studio 2013 or newer. It might exist in designer in visual studio, I will have a look.

Comment: I use VS 2012. I don't understand why I should use Blend. I think it should not be an obligation to use a tool to develop, even if it makes it easier. Moreover, it's a way to get around my problem and sadly it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Obligation or not, it makes your development easier. I believe it to be free with 2012, but more than one way to skin a cat.